Why the external cannot receive the GitLab "Reset password instructions" mail
Somehow there is no "Reset password instructions" mail sent to the external users.
But the other users can receive the "Reset password instructions" mail.
My gitlab.rb is as follows:


Check your log files, both from gitlab and from the SMTP server.
